# Перенос бд из postgresql на mssql

Tags: postgresql, sql-server

Собственно вопрос в заголовке - как перенести бд из одной субд в другую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй покопать Мастер импорта и экспорта данных Sql Server, который поставляется вместе с Sql Server (Непомню точно в какой редакции). Я думаю с помощью него можно попробовать решить проблему